# 'ϵ-δ' proof for the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need help writing a formal 'ϵ-δ' proof for the following sequence:

> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}(n+2)^2 \sin(1/n)=\infty $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a *series* or *sequence* that you're finding the limit of?  Also, what do you think the limit should be?  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @user111893: Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MhenniBenghorbal, I didn't know how to type it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Write a rigorous proof using that $$\sin n^{-1}\sim n^{-1}$$